# Diy Water park tipping bucket physics

Tags: forces

So I'm building a tipping water bucket like the ones at a water park, just much smaller. I want the bucket to tip at 500mL. I'm currently using 3 inch PVC pipe cut 11 cm down crosswise. I can have any amount of weight at the bottom, so I was planning on 50 grams. I want to know, where can I place my 8mm diameter rod to get a quick and instantaneous dumping motion? I'm currently placing the rod 5cm from the bottom and I've tried multiple tries from 2 to 5mm off center. These first trials were unsuccessful because the bucket would tip just enough water out to stabilize it and it'd stay in that limbo. Where should the rod be?

Answer (score 0):

To get a quick "dumping" motion you need to place your tipping axis below the centre of gravity of a full bucket. As the bucket fills, the centre of gravity rises, and once it is above the axis the bucket becomes unstable and will tip over. Once the water has emptied the weight at the bottom of the bucket will bring it upright again.

You may also get better results if you use asymmetric bucket shapes, like this [Bucket Fountain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_Fountain) kinetic sculpture in Wellington, New Zealand.